# Select2 no funciona el buscar PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, select2

Hola buen día estoy usando el js select2 para llenar un combo, logre llenarlo pero la búsqueda ahora no funciona por ningún carácter.

Este es mi código js

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
// $('#panel_mantenimiento').hide();
$('#reg_id').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: '../ajax/region.php?op=region_listar_combo',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                q: params.term,
                page: params.page
              };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
    }
  });
```

});

Comment: puedes revisar este link http://www.brytestudio.com/blog/select2-quick-guide-to-install-and-configuration/